# Angular 2 send empty post

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular

I'm trying to send data from my application to the server using POST request but my server receives empty POST.

Here is the sending function :

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

postCharacter(mule: Mule): Promise<Mule> {

    return this.http.post(
            "http://www.super-secret-url.com/testPost.php", 
            { data: mule }, 
            { headers: this.headers }
        )
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as any)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The (very) simple php script :

```php
 <?
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($_POST);
 ?>
```

Request payload (data sent, from chrome developer console):

```
{
  "data": {
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "John",
    "Class": "Adventurer",
    "Items": [
      "641",
      "642",
      "643",
      "513",
      "512"
    ]
  }
}
```

The php script return en empty Json : []

I tried JSON.stringify to the data with no success.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

**Edit :**

Here is a screenshot from developer console :
[image]

**Edit 2 :**

When using put, the data is retreive server side. This is a probleme with angular 2 POST

Comment: Did you check the developer console in the browser `F12` network-tab ajax response ?? And do an `exit;` after `echo json_encode($_POST);` and remove the closing tag `?>` to prevent illegal output within the json-data like spaces..

Comment: Yes I checked the developer console, response is empty. I tried removing closing tag and add an exit, still empty :(

Comment: What did you expect in `$_POST`? Did you test `$_REQUEST`? Did you `var_dump($_POST)` to see if everthing is set up right? Did you test `echo json_encode(array('myJson'=>'testData'));`? Try to find the buggy part of your app.!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not server side. I tried `var_dump($_POST)` and  `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, still empty array. I also tried `echo json_encode(array('myJson'=>'testData'));` and I receive the data.

Comment: Did you notice that the request payload is json not POST data? Remove the Header when doing the http.post. The header is only needed if send from the server, so javascript (or any app. on client) knows that the plaindata can be converted to an json object.

Comment: Yes I noticed, that's why I tried adding a header at first. But this is strange, I just changed the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the request header still contains `application/json`

Comment: I faced the same problem, however converting body content with JSON.stringify(mule) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a cors issue try to update your code to this

```
      postCharacter(mule: Mule): Promise<Mule> {
      let headers = new Headers(this.headers);
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.post(
              "http://www.super-secret-url.com/testPost.php",mule,options  
          )
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json() as any)
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: you will need to import these
`import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: I can't assign options to headers :
Argument of type '{ headers: RequestOptions; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
      Property 'append' is missing in type 'RequestOptions'.

Comment: still empty post :(

Comment: can you see the request payload in browser's network tab ?

Comment: you can use `https://mpant.quora.com/A-simple-HTTP-service-using-Angular2-with-errror-handling` to see how to write a simple ajax service in angular2

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the request header and the payload. The url you provided lead to a page not found

Comment: try to var_dump $_REQUEST

Comment: Already tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939360/angular-2-send-empty-post/41939678?noredirect=1#comment71060382_41939360

Comment: `https://mpant.quora.com/A-simple-HTTP-service-using-Angular2-with-errror-handling`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me eventually:

```
postCharacter(mule: Mule): Promise<Mule> {

return this.http.post(
        "http://www.super-secret-url.com/testPost.php", 
        mule, 
        { headers: this.headers }
    )
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as any)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The server will not receive an *array*.

Decode it on the server using

`$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`